# How to pass a reference to a Boolean in es6 or better solution for Vue

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am picking up a Vue project and would like to pass a reference to a "spinner" for fetch requests. If an error, I'd like to pass a reference in the checkIfError method below rather than just the Boolean value. Something like this:

```
checkIfError(response, loadingStatus){
  if (!response.ok) {
    loadingStatus = false; // I'd like to set this.loadingQuotes to false and not set true to false
    const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
    msg = "this is jacked up";
    alert(message);
    throw new Error(message);
  }
},
getQuotes(){
  this.loadingQuotes = true;
  const response = await fetch("/quotes");
  this.checkIfError(response, this.loadingQuotes);

 }
```

But this obviously doesn't work. How could I pass a reference this way?

I was thinking of passing an object literal like `this.checkIfError(response, {targetStatus: this.loadingQuotes})` but suspect this just passes {status: true}.

Comment: Why not simply `return` a value instead of using an output parameter?

Comment: Are you calling `checkIfError` from multiple places?

Comment: Yes, I am calling in multiple places. Sorry for such a basic question  - I'm just a bit stumped trying to figure this out.

Comment: Can you show some other of these places, or do they all follow the exact same pattern? What do you even use `this.loadingQuotes` for in your component?

Comment: What is rather smelly is that you set `this.loadingQuotes = true` inside one function but want to set `this.loadingQuotes = false` in a different function. Really, just do both in `getQuotes`. No reason to let `checkIfError` do that.

Comment: It'll follow pretty much the same pattern. `this.loadingQuotes` is just a flag for showing a loading spinner in the UI next to the specific button.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you on that. Honestly, I was kinda getting curious  about how to do this.

Comment: Pass the object of which the flag is a property, then set `ref.loadingQuotes = false`. And that reference is `this`, which you coincidentally already do pass implicitly… :D

Comment: I suggest using Vuex for this kind of work, how about it? (https://vuex.vuejs.org/)